# static ip settings of illumos, openindiana

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I'd just download Openindiana (OI-hipster-gui-20170502.iso)
and install it on my VirtualBox(5.1.22, macOS 10.12.5)
Two network interface enabled, one for NAT another for bridge(i want to use it in static ip)

```
# svcadm disable network/physical:nwam
# svcadm enable network/physical:default
# ipadm enable-if -t e1000g1
# ipadm create-addr -T static -a a.b.c.d/24 e1000g1/v4
ipadm: Could not create address: Persistent operation on temporary object
```

How can I configure it?

using Solaris11.3, i did

```
# ipadm create-ip net1
# ipadm create-addr -T static -a a.b.c.d/24 net1/v4
```

works fine.

Anybody tell me the difference between OpenIndiana(Illumos) and Solaris11

Best regards,